# How to use npm file-storage package?

Tags: javascript, file, npm, storage, file-storage

I learn Javascript and don't even know, how exactly use FileStorage object.

```js
var storage = new FileStorage(...); // supply valid credentials
```

The package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-storage

What means "supply valid credentials"?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Also, are you sure you want to use a package that hasn't seen any activity in five years?

Comment: @NicoHaase, just need to store files. Is activity important?

Comment: what means "supply valid credentials"  in a comment?

Comment: Have found the answer in Ubuntu. Check this https://askubuntu.com/a/1337634/1236973